# Adjusting beam for chords with two sizes notes in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the beam for chords with two sizes notes in Musixtex, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{musixtex}
%\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \parindent0mm
    \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    %\setstaffs{1}{2}
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece 
    \notes\hsk&\hsk\en
    \notes\isluru1p\zq g{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.05\elemskip} \qu{j}}&\isluru2l\Ibl1ll{5}\qb1{l}\en
    \notes\qsk&\qb1{k}\en
    \notes\zq{j}\curve {3}33\tslur1m{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.2\elemskip} \ql{m}}&\qb1{l}\en
    \notes\qsk&\tqb1o\en
    \notes\isluru4o\ibl3l{-5}\zqb3{l}{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.2\elemskip} \qb3{o}}&\ibl0l{-5}\qb0{n}\en
    \notes\zqb3{j}{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.2\elemskip} \tqb3{m}}&\qb0{l}\en
    \notes\zq g\tslur4p{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.03\elemskip} \qu{j}}&\qb0{j}\curve {8}77\tslur2g\tqb0g\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow (note that the beam needs to be adjusted):
[image: desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted a lot of brackets, and some spaces. I changed the order of some elements.
I defined an hsize, to see whether the horizontal position would be good after musixflx.

```
\documentclass{report}%
\usepackage{musixtex}%
%\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}%

\begin{music}%
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \hsize=60mm%
    \parindent0mm
    \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}%
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \instrumentnumber{2}%
    %\setstaffs{1}{2}
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece 
    \notes\hsk&\hsk\en%
\notes\ibsluru1i\zq g\tinynotesize\off{0.3\elemskip}\stemlength{6}%
\qu j\normalnotesize\off{-0.3\elemskip}\sk\zq j\tinynotesize%\curve333
   \stemlength{6}\tslur1g\ql m\normalnotesize\sk &\isluru2l\Ibl1ll3\qb1{lkl}\tqb1o\en%
   %
\notes\isluru4o\ibl3l{-5}\zqb3l\tinynotesize\qb3o\normalnotesize%\stemlength{6}
    \tbl3\zqb3j\tinynotesize\qb3m\normalnotesize\tbsluru4o\zq g\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{0.3\elemskip}\qu j\sk&\ibl0l{-5}\qb0{n}\qb0{l}\qb0{j}\curve677\tslur2g\tqb0g\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}%


\end{document}
```

[image: beams]

Comment: Excellent result.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the space inside: `{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.02\elemskip}\qb3{o}}`, now the beams gets fine, but vertical line adjustment still is needed. The partial solved code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{musixtex}
%\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \parindent0mm
    \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    %\setstaffs{1}{2}
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece 
    \notes\hsk&\hsk\en
    \notes\isluru1p\zq g{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.05\elemskip} \qu{j}}&\isluru2l\Ibl1ll{5}\qb1{l}\en
    \notes\qsk&\qb1{k}\en
    \notes\zq{j}\curve {3}33\tslur1m{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.2\elemskip} \ql{m}}&\qb1{l}\en
    \notes\qsk&\tqb1o\en
    \notes\isluru4o\ibl3l{-5}\zqb3{l}{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.02\elemskip}\qb3{o}}&\ibl0l{-5}\qb0{n}\en
    \notes\zqb3{j}{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.01\elemskip}\tqb3{m}}&\qb0{l}\en
    \notes\zq{g}\tslur4p{\stemlength{6}\tinynotesize\off{-0.03\elemskip} \qu{j}}&\qb0{j}\curve {8}77\tslur2g\tqb0g\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The partially solved output is (note that is needed vertical alignment):
[image: solved_partially]